# Do I need a ground for a 2-wire BX cable to a stove?

Tags: grounding, stove

I am installing a new electric stove in a 20 year old condo. The existing BX cable has only 2 wires and both are hot legs. Do I need a ground wire or can I use the BX armor as the ground??

Comment: I believe it is no longer permissible to use BX armor as ground.  You are allowed to *add* a ground wire to pre-existing wiring.  The ground wire does not need to follow the same route as the conductors, but needs to be installed consistent with code and generally in a workmanlike manner.   In the relaxed rules in NEC 2014, you don't need to go all the way back to the panel if you can reach another circuit served by the same panel whose ground wire is thick enough.

Comment: Is this type AC or type MC?

Comment: Also, is this stove 120V-only, 120/240V, or 240V-only?  It sounds like something bigger is wrong than simply a missing ground!

Answer (score -1):

2014 NEC 250.118.10 all 3 examples of using Metal Clad include the use of a grounded conductor. In the 2014 NEC handbook 330.108 states. "the interlocked sheath cable construction is not recognized as an EGC." so it would not be lega. A discrete conductor is needed for the Equipment Grounding Conductor.

Comment: "BX" typically corresponds to AC not MC AIUI...

Comment: 330.108 is referring to MC cable, not AC/BX